# Connection refused between two containers

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, geoserver

I've two containers:

- DOCKERIZED-PYTHON: test python project that use flask and owslib3
- DOCKERIZED-GEOSERVER: Geoserver version from [here](https://github.com/MaxDragonheart/docker-geoserver)

I need to read some information from a WMS like layer title or bounding box. I use a JSON file on DOCKERIZED-PYTHON for call a WMS:

```
{
  "url": "https://geoserver.massimilianomoraca.me",
  "workspace": "MassimilianoMoraca",
  "service_version": "1.3.0",
  "layer_name": "edificicasalnuovo",
  "layer_type": "vector"
}
```

When I use this configuration I can see the information related to every layer on my server; this happen both if I start a project in local or inside a container.
But when I try to use DOCKERIZED-GEOSERVER with the JSON below:

```
{
  "url": "http://geoserver",
  "workspace": "tiger",
  "service_version": "1.3.0",
  "layer_name": "poi",
  "layer_type": "vector"
}
```

I see this error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='geoserver', port=80): Max retries exceeded
> with url:
> /geoserver/tiger/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0
> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection
> object at 0x7f8fd6c13a60>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Here my docker compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  geoserver:
    image: maxdragonheart/geoserver
    environment:
      GS_VERSION: ${GS_VERSION}
      GS_DEMO_DATA: ${GS_DEMO_DATA}
      GS_HTTP_PORT: ${GS_HTTP_PORT}
      GS_INITIAL_MEMORY: ${GS_INITIAL_MEMORY}
      GS_MAXIMUM_MEMORY: ${GS_MAXIMUM_MEMORY}
    container_name: dev_geoserver
    restart: always
    ports:
    - ${GS_HTTP_PORT}:8080
    volumes:
    - geoserver:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver
    networks:
      - test

  python-api:
    image: maxdragonheart/${PROJECT_NAME}
    build:
      context: ./pythonapi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      PROJECT_NAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}
    container_name: dev_pythonapi
    restart: always
    ports:
    - ${PYTHON_API_PORT}:5000
    depends_on:
      - geoserver
    networks:
      - test

volumes:
  geoserver:

networks:
  test:
    driver: bridge
```

Probably there is a mistake with network but this is not clear for me. Someone can explain to me this point?

Comment: If the geoserver process is listening on port 8080 (as its `ports:` suggest) then that needs to be in the configured URL as well; `http://geoserver:8080`.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze, now it's run. If you add an answer I vote it